# Password authentification between PHP and Smartphone devices

Tags: php, objective-c, authentication, ssl, hash

I am using this class in order to create password hashes. The system consist of a a webpage built upon php, iphone devices and also android devices. I need these smartphones to be able to log in and access the information stored in my DB server side. What is the best solution, is it to port this method to objective c and send the hash to the server? Or is it better to send the password using SSL and to compare the hash server side?

```
class PassHash {

  // blowfish
  private static $algo = '$2a';

  // cost parameter
  private static $cost = '$10';

  // mainly for internal use
  public static function unique_salt() {
    return substr(sha1(mt_rand()),0,22);
  }

  // this will be used to generate a hash
  public static function hash($password) {

    return crypt($password,
                self::$algo .
                self::$cost .
                '$' . self::unique_salt());

  }

  // this will be used to compare a password against a hash
  public static function check_password($hash, $password) {

    $full_salt = substr($hash, 0, 29);

    $new_hash = crypt($password, $full_salt);

    return ($hash == $new_hash);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"porting the hash" to the mobile apps would not be a good idea. The server's hash is unique, and you wouldn't want different "hash" methods across different device platforms.

Send the password in SSL and let your server-side authentication model do the hashing.